# How can I visualize the weights(variables) in cnn in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

After training the cnn model, I want to visualize the weight or print out the weights, what can I do?
I cannot even print out the variables after training.
Thank you!

Comment: Also, take a look at the tensorboard example:  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/225

Comment: See also: [How can visualize tensorflow convolution filters?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39361943/562769)

Answer (score 37):

To visualize the weights, you can use a [`tf.image_summary()`](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train.html#image_summary) op to transform a convolutional filter (or a slice of a filter) into a summary proto, write them to a log using a [`tf.train.SummaryWriter`](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/train.html#SummaryWriter), and visualize the log using [TensorBoard](http://tensorflow.org/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html).

Let's say you have the following (simplified) program:

```
filter = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([8, 8, 3]))
images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 28, 28])

conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, filter, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME")

# More ops...
loss = ...
optimizer = tf.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss)

filter_summary = tf.image_summary(filter)

sess = tf.Session()
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter('/tmp/logs', sess.graph_def)
for i in range(10000):
  sess.run(train_op)
  if i % 10 == 0:
    # Log a summary every 10 steps.
    summary_writer.add_summary(filter_summary, i)
```

After doing this, you can start TensorBoard to visualize the logs in `/tmp/logs`, and you will be able to see a visualization of the filter.

Note that this trick visualizes depth-3 filters as RGB images (to match the channels of the input image). If you have deeper filters, or they don't make sense to interpret as color channels, you can use the [`tf.split()`](http://tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#split) op to split the filter on the depth dimension, and generate one image summary per depth.

Comment: What if I just want to print it out? How can I reach a variable with name_scope ike "conv1" whose name is 'weight'?

Comment: If you just want to print out the variable, you can pass the `tf.Variable` object to `sess.run()` and it will return a numpy array containing the weights.

Comment: @ Wuchen  Here's how you can get a variable "weight" under scope "conv1" --    with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope_conv: weights = tf.get_variable('weights')

Comment: Note that the syntax has changed in later versions to `tf.image_summary(tag, tensor, ...)`

Comment: And `tf.image_summary` is now deprecated since 2016-11-30 and replaced with `tf.summary.image` cf. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/ops/logging_ops.py

Answer (score 22):

Like @mrry said, you can use `tf.image_summary`. For example, for `cifar10_train.py`, you can put this code somewhere under `def train()`. Note how you access a var under scope 'conv1'

```
# Visualize conv1 features
with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope_conv:
  weights = tf.get_variable('weights')

  # scale weights to [0 255] and convert to uint8 (maybe change scaling?)
  x_min = tf.reduce_min(weights)
  x_max = tf.reduce_max(weights)
  weights_0_to_1 = (weights - x_min) / (x_max - x_min)
  weights_0_to_255_uint8 = tf.image.convert_image_dtype (weights_0_to_1, dtype=tf.uint8)

  # to tf.image_summary format [batch_size, height, width, channels]
  weights_transposed = tf.transpose (weights_0_to_255_uint8, [3, 0, 1, 2])

  # this will display random 3 filters from the 64 in conv1
  tf.image_summary('conv1/filters', weights_transposed, max_images=3)
```

If you want to visualize all your `conv1` filters in one nice grid, you would have to organize them into a grid yourself. I did that today, so now I'd like to share a [gist for visualizing conv1 as a grid](https://gist.github.com/kukuruza/03731dc494603ceab0c5)

Comment: Works for me! Thanks

Comment: if the channels is 16, how to do to visualize it?

Comment: @raptoravis There is no default way, and it does not make much sense. I am guessing this is not for the first layer. If I wanted to do that though, I would modify the gist in the answer to display 16 grids, each for 1 channel (grayscale)

Comment: @etoropov yes,you are right, it is for the 2nd layer. thanks to you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 7):

You can extract the values as numpy arrays the following way:

```
with tf.variable_scope('conv1', reuse=True) as scope_conv:
    W_conv1 = tf.get_variable('weights', shape=[5, 5, 1, 32])
    weights = W_conv1.eval()
    with open("conv1.weights.npz", "w") as outfile:
        np.save(outfile, weights)
```

Note that you have to adjust the scope (`'conv1'` in my case) and the variable name (`'weights'` in my case).

Then it boils down on visualizing numpy arrays. One example how to visualize numpy arrays is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""Visualize numpy arrays."""

import numpy as np
import scipy.misc

arr = np.load('conv1.weights.npb')

# Get each 5x5 filter from the 5x5x1x32 array
for filter_ in range(arr.shape[3]):
    # Get the 5x5x1 filter:
    extracted_filter = arr[:, :, :, filter_]

    # Get rid of the last dimension (hence get 5x5):
    extracted_filter = np.squeeze(extracted_filter)

    # display the filter (might be very small - you can resize the window)
    scipy.misc.imshow(extracted_filter)
```

Comment: I had to use `with open("conv1.weights.npz", "wb") as outfile:` (note the b) with python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `tensorflow 2 API`, There are several options:

Weights extracted using the  `get_weights()` function.

`weights_n = model.layers[n].get_weights()[0]`

Bias extracted using the `numpy()` convert function.

`bias_n = model.layers[n].bias.numpy()`