# How to visualize learned filters on tensorflow

Tags: filter, visualization, tensorflow

Similarly to the Caffe framework, where it is possible to watch the learned filters during CNNs training and it's resulting convolution with input images, I wonder if is it possible to do the same with TensorFlow?

A Caffe example can be viewed in this link:

> http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/00-classification.ipynb

Grateful for your help!

Comment: You could use the [tensorflow debugger](https://github.com/ericjang/tdb) tool

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. Thanks! However, tensorboard should have this feature.

Comment: See also [How can visualize tensorflow convolution filters?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39361943/562769)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I visualize the weights(variables) in cnn in Tensorflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783672/how-can-i-visualize-the-weightsvariables-in-cnn-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Thanks! that's what i looking for! thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To see just a few conv1 filters in Tensorboard, you can use this code (it works for cifar10)

```
# this should be a part of the inference(images) function in cifar10.py file

# conv1
with tf.variable_scope('conv1') as scope:
  kernel = _variable_with_weight_decay('weights', shape=[5, 5, 3, 64],
                                       stddev=1e-4, wd=0.0)
  conv = tf.nn.conv2d(images, kernel, [1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
  biases = _variable_on_cpu('biases', [64], tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
  bias = tf.nn.bias_add(conv, biases)
  conv1 = tf.nn.relu(bias, name=scope.name)
  _activation_summary(conv1)

  with tf.variable_scope('visualization'):
    # scale weights to [0 1], type is still float
    x_min = tf.reduce_min(kernel)
    x_max = tf.reduce_max(kernel)
    kernel_0_to_1 = (kernel - x_min) / (x_max - x_min)

    # to tf.image_summary format [batch_size, height, width, channels]
    kernel_transposed = tf.transpose (kernel_0_to_1, [3, 0, 1, 2])

    # this will display random 3 filters from the 64 in conv1
    tf.image_summary('conv1/filters', kernel_transposed, max_images=3)
```

I also wrote a simple [gist](https://gist.github.com/kukuruza/03731dc494603ceab0c5) to display all 64 conv1 filters in a grid.

Comment: Do you place this piece of code inside the "inference" function of the cifar 10 script?

Comment: I didn't, but that's a good idea :) I've just updated the code accordingly

Comment: Works! thanks! I was having an error with "convert_image_dtype" so i changed `tf.image.convert_image_dtype(kernel_0_to_1, dtype=tf.uint8)` to `kernel_0_to_255_uint8 = tf.cast(kernel_0_to_1, dtype=tf.float32)`.

Comment: Strange - I didn't have any errors.. Well, apparently Tensorboard can also visualize float images in range [0, 1]. Btw, `kernel_0_to_1` is already of type float, so your cast is redundant. I updated the code

Comment: It works only in conv1. How about conv2, conv3 ... ?

Comment: @m0z4rt It does not make much sense to visualize filters from conv2 and deeper. [Other methods](https://github.com/InFoCusp/tf_cnnvis) are used for that. That said, you can modify the gist code to show N grayscale grids where N is the number of the channels on input (each grid showing one channel for all filters).