# How can visualize tensorflow convolution filters?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

[image: Example]

In many documents, there are images about each filter like "Example".
I want to visual my convolution filters like "Example" image, but I don't know how can visualize it.

How can I visualize my convolution filters?

Comment: See also: [How to visualize learned filters on tensorflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35759220/562769)

Comment: See also: [How can I visualize the weights(variables) in cnn in Tensorflow?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33783672/562769)

Comment: Those images aren't the filters themselves, I believe. I think they are images that have been optimized to maximize the response of certain filters.

Comment: @chris Incorrect, these are the AlexNet first convolutional layer filters on the left figure, and the right figure is the filters from a network trained in the Dropout paper.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about each convolutional filter as `x` by `x` matrix, where `x` is the size of the filter. So your task is to put those matrices on a plot grid. I have made an example how to plot convolutional filters and output of convolutional layers using MNIST dataset, see [conviz repository on github](https://github.com/grishasergei/conviz). Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 5):

No those aren't the filters. You can read [this paper](https://cs.nyu.edu/~fergus/papers/zeilerECCV2014.pdf) which describes the procedures from converting the layer L's filters into these images. 
In short words what it does is taking some filter, and uses a technique similar but not the same as back-propagation to convert the filter into an image.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the 2d convolution is a tensor `[batch, in_height, in_width, in_channels]`. The image can be represented as a matrix `[in_height, in_width, in_channels]`. So all you need to do is to grab a few images from your batch, and add them to your summary with [`tf.summary.image()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/summary/image).

For a tutorial how to do this, take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33794463/1090562).