# Visualize conv2d filter for TensorBoard image_summary

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorboard

I want to visualize the filter weights of my CNN. They are of size `height`x`width`x`input`x`output`.

However, TensorBoard requires the image_summary to be a Tensor of shape `batches`x`height`x`width`x`channels`.

How can I convert my filter weights to the correct form?

Some context:

```
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5, 5, 1, 64]), name='W1')
conv = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W1, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')
```

Answer (score 1):

A normal image batch has shape `[batch, height, width, 3]` so you can make Tensorboard show a batch of colored images for the first convolution layer by transposing the filters to `[output, height, width, 3]`. This answer has the code: [How to visualize learned filters on tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35759220/how-to-visualize-learned-filters-on-tensorflow).

For weights in other layers, you can only show `input * output` grayscale images. You first need to split the tensor along input/output channel,  transpose and concatenate the tensor to shape `[input * output, height, width, 1]`. You can find some example code here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/908