# How to visualize keras convolutional filters in Tensorboard with eager execution

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

Given the following model, is it possible to get images from each convolutional filter?  I can't seem to find a way through this.

```
    tf.enable_eager_execution()

    l = tf.keras.layers
    max_pool = l.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), (2, 2), padding='same', data_format=data_format)

    kmodel = tf.keras.Sequential(
        [
            l.Reshape(target_shape=input_shape, input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE * colors,)),
            l.Conv2D(32, (5,5), padding='same', data_format=data_format, activation=tf.nn.relu),
            max_pool,
            l.Conv2D(64, (5,5), padding='same', data_format=data_format, activation=tf.nn.relu),
            max_pool,
            l.Conv2D(128, (5,5), padding='same', data_format=data_format, activation=tf.nn.relu),
            max_pool,
            l.Conv2D(256, (5,5), padding='same', data_format=data_format, activation=tf.nn.relu),
            max_pool,
            l.Flatten(),
            l.Dense(1024, activation=tf.nn.relu),
            l.Dropout(0.4),
            l.Dense(num_classes) #num_classes
        ]
    )

# how to get tf.contrib.image for each of the 4 filters?
```

Getting close but no cigar:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35858950

https://github.com/InFoCusp/tf_cnnvis

Thanks!

Clarification update: also using tf.GradientTape API

Comment: After much searching, it appears that currently there is no library-based way to achieve this (including beholder), if you are also using tf.GradientTape and eager execution with tf.keras models.  Basically you'd have to write code to access the model layers, and generate the output.