# How to print first channel of the filter?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the following code I want to print 1st channel of the filter. How can I do that? I want to print 2 by 2 filter but if I print filter[:,:,0] it gives me a 3rd order tensor shouldn't it be simply 2 by 2 filter?

```
graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    filter= tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2,2,3,32]))

    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)
    print(sess.run(filter))
```

Comment: Try the approach outlined in the first answer and subsequently index into the resulting NumPy array and visualize it with SciPy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783672/how-can-i-visualize-the-weightsvariables-in-cnn-in-tensorflow

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your point.I want to print filters

Comment: `filter` is 4-dimensional, and slicing with `[:,:,0]` is equivalent to slicing with `[:,:,0,:]`, that is why you get a 3-dimensional tensor.