# Find Most Important Input from a Neural Network

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I trained a neural network with 37 Inputs. It has around 85% accuracy. Is it possible for me to find out which Input has the most effect.  I tried this code but I cannot figure out how to find most important Input

```
weights = model.layers[0].get_weights()[0]
biases = model.layers[0].get_weights()[1]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible solution is to wrap your model with [`keras.wrappers.scikit_learn`](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/) and then use [Recursive Feature elimination](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_rfe_digits.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-rfe-digits-py) in scikit-learn:

```
def create_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

model = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=100, batch_size=128, verbose=0)
rfe = RFE(estimator=model, n_features_to_select=1, step=1)
rfe.fit(X, y)
ranking = rfe.ranking_.reshape(digits.images[0].shape)

# Plot pixel ranking
plt.matshow(ranking, cmap=plt.cm.Blues)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title("Ranking of pixels with RFE")
plt.show()
```

[image: ranking pixel with rfe]

If you need to visualize weights see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33783672/how-can-i-visualize-the-weightsvariables-in-cnn-in-tensorflow).

Comment: The example does not seem to work anymore as it throws the following error: `AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute '_get_tags'`.